# Cannot get didEnd(_contact: SKPhysicsContact) to work properly in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, bitmask

```
 func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & Constants().playerCategoryBitMask != 0)
    {

        if(secondBody.categoryBitMask & Constants().borderCategoryBitMask == 4)
        {       touchingWall = true
                print("Touching the wall ");
        }
    }
 }
```

didBegin is working great!

However didEnd not sure how to do it?

```
func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & Constants().borderCategoryBitMask != 0 )
    {

        if(secondBody.categoryBitMask & Constants().playerCategoryBitMask != 0 )
        {
            touchingWall = false
            print("Not Touching the wall ");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have

```
let playerCategoryBitMask:UInt32 =  1
let borderCategoryBitMask:UInt32 = 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is because you´re using a method called the [`bitwise AND operator (&)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29).**

> The bitwise AND operator (&) combines the bits of two numbers. It
>   returns a new number whose bits are set to 1 only if the bits were
>   equal to 1 in both input numbers:

[image]

```
let eightBits1: UInt8 = 0b00000001
let eightBits2: UInt8  = 0b00000001
let lastBit = eightBits1 & eightBits2  // equals 0b00000001
```

Combining the bits only the last bit 1 would return 1 all the rest would return zero.

**A simpler explanation:**

I declare two variables:

```
let x = 1
let y = 1
```

Here both x and y has the value 1, when you use bitwise AND operator the result will be also 1 and when checking if the result it is not equal to zero it would be true (any result that it is not equal to zero would return true).

```
let eightBits1: UInt8 = 0b00000001 // 1
let eightBits2: UInt8  = 0b00000001 // 1
let lastBit = eightBits1 & eightBits2  // equals 0b00000001 // 2
```

The result would always be the same as `x` (which is equal to `y`) in this case `1`.

```
if (x & y) != 0 {
    print("Same")
} else {
    print("Not same")
}
```

In this case:

```
let x = 1
let y = 2

let eightBits1: UInt8 = 0b00000001  // 1
let eightBits2: UInt8  = 0b00000010 // 2
let noBits = eightBits1 & eightBits2  // equals 0 -> 0b00000000
```

You get `false` and not same will be printed out since the result of the bitwise operator it IS equal to zero

**Basically, if you use the `Bitwise AND operator` using two identical numbers the result will always be the same number.**

**To your issue:**
In your `didBegin`, you´re comparing:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategoryBitMask) != 0
```

Here your `firstBody.categoryBitMask` is 1 and `playerCategoryBitMask` is also 1 hence `true` and you enter the if-statement.

In your `didEnd` you´re comparing:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & Constants().borderCategoryBitMask) != 0
```

Here your `firstBody.categoryBitMask` is 1 and `borderCategoryBitMask` is 4 hence the result is `zero` and you don´t enter the if-statement because 0 it is equal to zero.

Now that you know this, you can modify your code and make it work.

Comment: Thank you Rashwan! So basically if I have the player stop touching the wall, what should the bitmask combination be?

001 & 100  which are 1 & 4 in decimal?

Comment: @Marin, np tried to be as specific as possible hence all the edits. The combinations 001 & 100 (1 and 4) will result in 000. To be able to match the combinations needs to be aligned (same bit/position).